# CKAN Implementation - Issue around CKAN API's to Create a Package and Resource

Tags: ckan

We are working with a client on a CKAN implementation and have run into a couple issues.

The particular issue we’re having is regarding using the CKAN APIs to create a package and resource.
They have external file that contains the metadata to be used for import against the CKAN package_create and resource_create APIs.

When they create CKAN entries that are package and resource only, without file uploads (files are CSV), the entries create successfully.
When they create CKAN entries combined with file uploads, the results are variable.

FYI, the CSV files have been imported through the CKAN interface successfully – about 15 files will be associated with 20k resources.
If you have any suggestions or examples of Python code used for the resource_create API that also uploads a file per resource, that would definitely help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use curl or Python library requests for creating a new resource and upload a file to it. Check this examples from file store API http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/filestore.html#filestore-api

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the examples for curl or requests (thanks Zoran), I suggest using the 'ckanapi' python library. See the example for uploading a file here:

https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi#action-arguments